# Trying to make my character respawn when variable playerlife goes lower than zero

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make it so my character is teleported to a respawn position when their life hits zero. Everything functions as intended besides the teleport mechanic. I have auto sync transforms enabled, but when my character reaches 0 (or less) it does not teleport my character. I have setup everything within the inspector as well, and have referenced my player object and my respawn point. Below is my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerLife : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static float playerLife = 200f;
    public float totaltime = 0f;
    public Transform respawn;
    public GameObject player;
    Text life;


    void Start()
    {
        life = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        life.text = "Health: " + playerLife;
        if (playerLife <= 0)
        {
            playerLife = 200;
            player.transform.position = respawn.transform.position;
        }

    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("healthpotion"))
            playerLife += 50f;
        if (collider.tag == "healthpotion")
            Destroy(collider.gameObject);
    }
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider collider)
    {
        totaltime += Time.deltaTime;
        if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("lava"))
        {
            if (totaltime > 1)
            {
                playerLife -= 1f;
                totaltime = 0f;
            }

        }
        if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("lavatwo"))
        {
            if (totaltime > 1)
            {
                playerLife -= 50f;
                totaltime = 0f;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the position for respawn. So instead of:

```
public Transform respawn;
```

Just use:

```
public Vector3 respawn = new Vector3(x, y, z);
```

Then:

```
player.transform.position = respawn;
```

Comment: It still does not work, did I understand you correctly?
Here is my updated script:
https://pastebin.com/MGmB1Ltj

Comment: That's really strange... I guess this is beyond me then. I'm upvoting this question.